# react native expo read data from object

Tags: react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBnsO.png)

My code

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';


export default function App() {
  
  async function permissions(){
    console.log("printing cameraroll")
  const {sp}= await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL)


  
  const s=await MediaLibrary.getAlbumsAsync("title")
  
  
  console.log(s);

  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Click-me" onPress={permissions} />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding:Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding:Constants.statusBarHeight
  },
});
```

i am trying to create a gallery type which will be part of my app so i want to read the title but i am unable to access the object

Comment: The image is the "console.log(s)"? and what exactly you want to acheive?

Comment: since i am creating a gallery i want to show the available albums  so i want to extract the title part which consists of the album names that are available in your mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a list of all titles you can do it like this:

```
const listOfTitles = MediaLibrary.getAlbumsAsync().map(album => album.title);
```

In case "getAlbumsAsync" returns a promise (documentation doesn't say so), then you can get it like this:

```
const albums = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumsAsync();
const listOfTitles = albums.map(album => album.title);
```

Comment: its working,its returning a promise thanks for your help

Comment: hey can you tell for this also i tried the same for MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync(options) firsst it crashed now its working fine but giving this error [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: albumss.map is not a function. (In 'albumss.map(function (album) {] i tired it changing to assets as in docs but same error

Comment: const albums = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync(options);
const listOfTitles = albums.map(album => album.title); rest of the code is same

Comment: but assets don't have title (see https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/media-library/#asset)

Comment: yeh got it sorted thanks it has to be called in a different way not like album

Comment: can we connect ? i am having lot of doubts and unable to get proper help from web i m getting struck quiet easily @D10S